# Where's The Tag Wiki for Flavor?

Tags: bug, tags

I recently got 2 rep for having an approved edit on the "flavor" badge as shown here:

```
+10  Are there any disadvantages to shade grown coffee?
+10  How hot should the water be for instant coffee?
+2   flavor tag wiki
+2   brewing-process tag wiki
```

So I checked the tag out and hoped to see my edit shown on the flavor badge. Then I found this weird quote when I clicked the "flavor" tag:

> The flavor tag has no wiki summary, can you help us create it?

What?! I just got an approved edit and it says there has been no edit or current summary.I clicked on it and it shows a piece of my summary (okay, not, hoc_age also edited this one plus brewing-process). Why isn't the tag summary for flavor showing properly? The brewing-process wiki (which I edited) was approved and is visible:

```
The process of brewing coffee, hot or cold. (hoc_age edited it so it is shorter than my original)
```

Comment: I had a similar problem this morning.  Text was submitted for both the tag wiki excerpt and the tag wiki for `kopiluwak` (should be hyphenated by SE standards, but I didn't create the tag).  The tag wiki Edit was accepted an hour ago, but the wiki excerpt seems to be MIA.  The excerpt really is just a shortened version of the wiki, so I cannot imagine a reviewer accepting the long version and not the excerpt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You suggested content/edit for the *flavor tag wiki*, but it looks like you did *not* suggest content/edit for the *flavor tag wiki **excerpt***. That's the reason that there was no content there: no one had yet put any content in the excerpt.  There are two different fields for the tag wiki: one for the "excerpt" (short version) and one for the main tag wiki.

Looking at the history of the universe, it looks like you suggested tag wiki edits to the following:

- temperature tag wiki
- temperature tag wiki excerpt
- brewing-process tag wiki
- brewing-process tag wiki excerpt
- bean-varieties tag wiki
- bean-varieties tag wiki excerpt
- flavor tag wiki

I.e., you suggested an edit to the "flavor tag wiki", but you did not submit a suggested edit for the "flavor tag wiki *excerpt*." I put in a placeholder for the "flavor tag wiki excerpt"; feel free to suggest an edit if you'd like.

I think everyone can view the history of the tag wikis and excerpts; see [the flavor tag wiki excerpt history here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/posts/1560/revisions).

Thank you for proposing content for the tag wikis!

Comment: @PythonMaster ... and relax! We're all in this together. :) If some words accidentally get swallowed by an errant click, the edit history is available for nearly all content... it can be rolled back, just like you did for the content on [this question](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/posts/1121/revisions)!